# How to get value from text_input in pygame-menu?

Tags: python, text, pygame, menu, return-value

I have a menu. In this menu, I have a "Name" field where the user enters his name. I need to take this name for further processing. How should I do it? I have some code:

```
menu.add.text_input('name:', default='player') # I NEED THIS VALUE.
menu.add.selector('difficulty', [('easy', "EASY"), ('medium', 'MEDIUM'), ('hard', 'HARD')], onchange=change_difficulty, style='fancy', style_fancy_arrow_margin=(0, 0, 0), style_fancy_bgcolor=(0, 0, 0, 0), style_fancy_bordercolor=(0, 0, 0, 0), style_fancy_arrow_color=(220, 132, 201))
menu.add.button('play', start_the_game, DIFFICULTY)
menu.add.button('quit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)

while True:

    screen.blit(bg_image, (0, 0))

    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    if menu.is_enabled():
        menu.update(events)
        menu.draw(screen)
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other event driven languages e.g. C# you need to bind a function to the on change event of your input field that you added in the menu so that your code will be like this

```
menu.add.text_input('name:', default='player', onchange= MyTextValue) # Function is bind here
menu.add.selector('difficulty', [('easy', "EASY"), ('medium', 'MEDIUM'), ('hard', 'HARD')], onchange=change_difficulty, style='fancy', style_fancy_arrow_margin=(0, 0, 0), style_fancy_bgcolor=(0, 0, 0, 0), style_fancy_bordercolor=(0, 0, 0, 0), style_fancy_arrow_color=(220, 132, 201))
menu.add.button('play', start_the_game, DIFFICULTY)
menu.add.button('quit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)

def MyTextValue(name):
    #on input change your value is returned here
    print('Player name is', name)

while True:

    screen.blit(bg_image, (0, 0))

    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    if menu.is_enabled():
        menu.update(events)
        menu.draw(screen)
    
    pygame.display.update()
```